# rest of paraghraph, in next page has no indent

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am really new to latex, and working with template which I have for my thesis. I am facing this problem, that the rest of paragraph in next page, doesn't have the same space from the borders. How can I solve this problem?[image]

Comment: Just a guess: you are using a two-sided layout. The margins are supposed to be different

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?